# jQuery Loop that Scrolls Text Between Divs

Tags: jquery

Good Morning,

I'm trying to do loop from div to div (Right to left) and then repeat.  The problem is I'm not able to repeat correctly.  I have stared at this code for hours and can't figure out a simple way to change the bottom number.

The loop iterates the variable correctly, but doesn't reset properly.  The results are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (then) 2, 3, 4, 5, 2.  It never returns to 1.  Any ideas?

I have tried the following:
1) Changing the bottom i = (i==5)?2:i+1; to i = (i==5)?1:i+1;  It does move the div correctly, but then completely stops the loop and doesn't iterate at all.  All the values change to 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.

2) I have tried iterate the loop outside of the loop to no avail.

3) Setup jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/covetech/awSLb/6/#&togetherjs=Msll5jT8qh

Here is what I'm trying to do:

CSS:

```
.menuItem1:after{
    content: 'Text 1';
}
.menuItem2:after{
    content: 'Text 2';
}
.menuItem3:after{
    content: 'Text 3';
}
.menuItem4:after{
    content: 'Text 4';
}
.menuItem5:after{
    content: 'Text 5';
}
```

Jquery:

```
var x = 0;
while (x<5){
    var i = 1;
    function changeClass(){

        $("#menuItem-item").removeClass("menuItem" + i)
        i = (i==5)?2:i+1;    
        $("#menuItem-item").addClass("menuItem" + (i));

        $("#menuItem-item1").removeClass("menuItem" + i)
        i = (i==5)?2:i+1;    
        $("#menuItem-item1").addClass("menuItem" + (i));

        $("#menuItem-item2").removeClass("menuItem" + i)
        i = (i==5)?2:i+1;    
        $("#menuItem-item2").addClass("menuItem" + (i));

        $("#menuItem-item3").removeClass("menuItem" + i)
        i = (i==5)?2:i+1;    
        $("#menuItem-item3").addClass("menuItem" + (i));

        $("#menuItem-item4").removeClass("menuItem" + i)
        i = (i==5)?2:i+1; 
        $("#menuItem-item4").addClass("menuItem" + (i));
    }
i = 1;
setInterval(changeClass, 3000);
```

Comment: Create a jsFiddle with your code, including your HTML, and then it might be possible to help you out.

Comment: Smart idea... I will do that now.  I forgot about that site...

Comment: jsFiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/covetech/awSLb/

Comment: Any luck with jsFiddle?  I'm still stuck.  Feel like I'm getting closer though...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'looping the div' meaning the divs should be shown 1 by 1 with increasing number and reset @ 5? Or you looping over the Divs just selecting them to for example change background-color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some JQuery magic.

the `append()` removes the selected element from it's parent and adds it to the new parent at the end of the line.

So something like this should give the desired effect.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeClass() {
    var $first = $('#container div').first();
    $('#container').append($first);
}

setInterval(changeClass, 3000);
```

Comment: Do you recommend a book?  I will buy and read it.  This was much easier then what I was doing...

Comment: It's just getting knowledge of the API's you are using. In this case JQuery.

Comment: Ok, I will just have to read up more than.  Thanks again for everything!  I will keep your contact information for the future...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your jQuery.

First off, your while loop condition checks `x`, but x is never updated in your loop so your loop is going forever.

Second, you've declared `var i` in your while loop so the reset at the bottom `i = 1` is pretty much redundant since you re-declare it every iteration. You should perhaps just declare it outside the loop at reset it once at the top.

```
var x = 0;
var i = 1;
while (x<5){
    i = 1;
    ...
```

Third, the last remove class in your function:

```
$("#menuItem-item4").removeClass("menuItem" + i)
i = (i==5)?2:i+1;
$("#menuItem-item4").addClass("menuItem" + (i));
```

If you trace your code (specifically follow the changes in `i`), you'll notice `i` is already 5 here, so it'll change to 2, rather than back to 1. So what's happening is you've removeClass() for `i=5`, then the condition changes `i` to 2, and you've addClass() for `i=2`. Maybe you should have your condition set `i` back to 1 for `menuItem-item4`:

```
$("#menuItem-item4").removeClass("menuItem" + i)
if(i==5)i=1
$("#menuItem-item4").addClass("menuItem" + (i));
```

Lastly, from editing your question, I can see the `setInterval()` is within the while loop. Close out your while loop properly and run `setInterval()` only once.

```
...
} // <-- add this so the setInterval is out of the while loop.
setInterval(changeClass, 3000);
```

Comment: I think at this point I started throwing everything at the proverbial wall and see what sticks.  I tried changing the last statement to: i = (i==5)?1:i+1; but it freezes all of the numbers and never cycles back.

The other numbers decrement perfectly.

Comment: @user3431223 I've edited my answer a bit, concerning the `i` declaration at the beginning and the `setInterval()` at the end.

Comment: i = (i==5)?1; for some reason causes a jquery error.

SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression
 

i = (i==5)?1;

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with jQuery, perhaps just have a `if(i==5)i=1` there then. No else.

Comment: Still no go.  It forces the entire loop to have the value 1.  It won't bump up, for some reason.